# Call javascript file with "start function" and "parameters"

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm developing a simple Electon application.

I have two javascript files (NodeJs). The first file is calling the second one.. My code is working...

I want to modify this line : `require('./mitm.js');` to accept parameters.
I want to add a start function in the mitm.js file and use object.start() in the main.js file, with parameters to configure the proxy and replace `"http://proxy:1111"`

Example : obj.start(param)

File 1 : main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')

const {app, BrowserWindow, session} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

//call mitm proxy
require('./mitm.js');

let win

function createWindow () {

    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 800})

     win.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:'localhost:8080'}, function () {
        win.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        })) 
    });

}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

File 2 : mitm.js

```
var HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

var Proxy = require('http-mitm-proxy');
var proxy = Proxy();

proxy.listen({
    port: 8080,
    httpAgent: new HttpProxyAgent("http://proxy:1111"), //example
    httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent("http://proxy:1111") //example
});

proxy.onRequest(function(ctx, callback) {

    console.log('-------- onRequest-------- ')
    // console.log(ctx)

    return callback();
});

proxy.onResponse(function(ctx, callback) {

    console.log('-------- onResponse-------- ')
    // console.log(ctx)

    return callback();
});
```

How can i do this in nodeJs?

Thank you

Comment: If you spawn new process, you can pass arguments by `process.argv`. If you want to invoke module from current process, just export default function from one module, require from another and invoke it with arguments.
In other words, don't do anything in root of module file. Just wrap it in default function and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `mitm.js`, add the function `start(param)`, place the logic within and then export it.

```
// mitm.js
var HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

var Proxy = require('http-mitm-proxy');
var proxy = Proxy();

function start (param) {
    proxy.listen({
        port: 8080,
        httpAgent: new HttpProxyAgent(param), 
        httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent(param)
    });

    proxy.onRequest(function(ctx, callback) {
        console.log('-------- onRequest-------- ')    
        return callback();
    });

    proxy.onResponse(function(ctx, callback) {
        console.log('-------- onResponse-------- ')
        return callback();
    });
}

// Return an object with the start function
module.exports = {start}
```

Now you can require `mitm.js` and then invoke the function `start()`

```
var mitm = require('./mitm')
mitm.start('http://proxy')
```

Comment: And how can I call this in the main.js?

Comment: @Devhercule its included at the bottom of the answer, refresh.

Comment: You supply `1111` as a port, but then you use `8080`. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm just supplying whatever data the question asker gave in the question.

Comment: @peteb Perfect, It's working for me, That's exactly what i need :) thank you

Comment: @petabe no problem, I just wanted to know it's use =)